# N2 CMS Asp.Net MVC 3 Razor ControlPanel HtmlHelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, content-management-system, razor, n2

I just bolted on the N2 CMS to my existing MVC 3 Razor site. So far no problems, things are editable etc. The only thing I'm missing is how to show the N2 control panel on the actual site rather than going to the /N2/ folder of the live site and editing things there.

Libardo, the lead developer of the N2 CMS hints at an HtmlHelper here http://n2cms.codeplex.com/discussions/232192 but I can't find it anywhere in the source code. I could likely roll my own but was just wondering if someone already did this or knows where the actual N2 version of the helper is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From discussions I've been following on the mailing list the HtmlHelper isn't in the main N2 build yet, but on another branch on github.

If you can't wait until this makes it into the main build, you could try putting the control in an ascx partial and using RenderPartial from your Razor views to render it.  I can't say I've tried this, but I'd be interested to hear if it works!

Comment: True - but you gave the right answer :) I feel bad, I forgot I asked the question here also. The branch is called dinamico for those interested.